# Hide all box classes and display only the target detail class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to hide all the classes with the same name and display only the one that is clicked. I've tried using parent, sibling and targeting as an object but it's not coming through. I found some working examples but when I apply them they don't. Any help will be much appreciated.

**JS**

```
 function more() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $(".detail").show();
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='mainwrapper'>
        <div class='superbox'> 
        <div class='box'> 
                    <img id='image-trend' src='http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlD9nQ_c_QAMBYW0BUhlp-1erh2x-1hTA2dLATwT_B3mKUv4xLHTtSxiBKqxtmAu29M9-26IOo'>    
                    <div id='box-title'>
                    Shirley Temple
                    </div> 
                    <div id='box-more'>
                    <img src='img/mini-clock.png' class='mini-clock'>Tue, 11 Feb 2014 12:00
                    </div>
                    <img id='image-trend-more' src='img/read-more.png' onclick='more(this)'>
                </div>

                <div class='detail'>
                <div id='spacer50'></div>
                <div id='det-box'>
                    <div id='det-box-head'>
                            <img id='image-trend-det' src='http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlD9nQ_c_QAMBYW0BUhlp-1erh2x-1hTA2dLATwT_B3mKUv4xLHTtSxiBKqxtmAu29M9-26IOo'>    
                            <div id='box-title-det'>
                            Shirley Temple
                            </div> 
                            <div id='box-more-det'>
                            <img src='img/mini-clock.png' class='mini-clock'>The Independent
                            </div>
                    </div>  
                        <div id='det-descript'><b>Shirley Temple</b> as she appears in &#39;The Littlest Rebel&#39; directed by David Butler, 1935 Temple made a further eight films with Fox, including Little Miss Marker and, thanks to her cherubic optimism and bouncing gold girls, she quickly became one of the <b>...</b></div>        
                        <div id='orig-det'><a href='http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/news/shirley-temple-dies-aged-85-9120936.html' target='_blank'><strong>Read trend on orign</strong></a></div>          
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class='superbox'> 
        <div class='box'> 
                    <img id='image-trend' src='http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0Zqjh_mR_qEWLw9NFW8p1LTDTeHurWmAwjoMN3lf_bp6L7MqlCDGw_utGdCrU9_9B627lBao'> 
                    <div id='box-title'>
                    Laurence Fishburne
                    </div> 
                    <div id='box-more'>
                    <img src='img/mini-clock.png' class='mini-clock'>Tue, 11 Feb 2014 03:00
                    </div>
                    <img id='image-trend-more' src='img/read-more.png' onclick='more(this)'>
                </div>

                <div class='detail'>
                <div id='spacer50'></div>
                <div id='det-box'>
                    <div id='det-box-head'>
                            <img id='image-trend-det' src='http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0Zqjh_mR_qEWLw9NFW8p1LTDTeHurWmAwjoMN3lf_bp6L7MqlCDGw_utGdCrU9_9B627lBao'> 
                            <div id='box-title-det'>
                            Shirley Temple
                            </div> 
                            <div id='box-more-det'>
                            <img src='img/mini-clock.png' class='mini-clock'>Sky News
                            </div>
                    </div>  
                        <div id='det-descript'>A broadcaster in Los Angeles has apologised to Samuel L Jackson after confusing him with Matrix star <b>Laurence Fishburne</b> in an interview. Jackson was being asked about his role in the new RoboCop film by KTLA&#39;s entertainment reporter when the mix-up&nbsp;<b>...</b></div>        
                        <div id='orig-det'><a href='http://news.sky.com/story/1209761/samuel-l-jackson-i-am-not-laurence-fishburne' target='_blank'><strong>Read trend on orign</strong></a></div>          
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you specify which elements need to be hidden `onclick`?

Comment: @DanielLisik I agree...the goal is very unclear and there is no css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `id` is unique, you need to change `id="image-trend-more"` to `class="image-trend-more"`

2) Try below code to check if it meets your requirements

```
$('.image-trend-more').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.box').hide().next('.detail').show();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GBw3E/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function more(el) {
    $(".detail").hide();
    $(el).closest('.superbox').find('.detail').show()
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fLSmx/)